# How to build a "large" swiped popover, like in the Mail app (iOS5, portrait mode)?

Tags: ios5, popover

I'd like to re-create the large popover we have in the mail app, in portrait mode, since iOS5.

You swipe from the left part of the screen and the rootView appears in a list-type popover.

Is it a private API ? I can't even find any documentation about it.

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've been able to do this is to use a UISplitViewController. Put the view which you want to occupy your entire window as your detail view, and the view within the "large" popover as the master.

The idea is to always have your master coming from the popover, instead of being docked on the side as it is by default in iOS5

After you've done the storyboard work above, make the detailViewController your splitViewControllerDelegate

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.splitViewController.delegate = self;
}
```

Lastly, implement the following UISplitViewControllerDelegate methods in the detailViewController

```
- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
//This ALWAYS hides the masterVC (in your case the rootVC) regardless of device orientation
    return YES;
}


- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc
{
// Assuming your detailViewController has a UIToolbar mapped to the .toolbar property
// This takes the barButtonItem from which your masterViewController "pops over"
// and places it in your UIToolbar
self.toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObject:barButtonItem];
}
```

Comment: p.s. if you figure out another way to do this, please share!